# type '(String) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a page using named route.

Routes in the main file:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'FlutterShare',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        accentColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: Home(),
      routes: {
        '/search': (BuildContext context) => Search(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Pushing to the page:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('BookClub'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/search');
              })
        ],
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
type '(String) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
The relevant error-causing widget was
  Search                            lib\main.dart:21
```

This is my first time building an app and i am not getting a solution.
Error is in the routes in main.dart file.

Search code:

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  Future<QuerySnapshot> searchResultsFuture;

      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.8),
      appBar: buildSearchField(),
      body: buildNoContent()
    );
  }
}

  AppBar buildSearchField() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: TextFormField(
        controller: searchController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Search for a book",
          filled: true,
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.account_box,
            size: 28.0,
          ),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ),
        onFieldSubmitted: null,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildNoContent() {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/search.svg',
              height: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 300.0 : 200.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Find Users",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 60.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hopefully this helps. I am stuck at this from past 3 hours and could not find anything to solve this.

Comment: According to given error message, you should check line 21 of main.dart

Comment: please share your Search code

Comment: @JideGuru added!

Comment: your main file says `home: Home()` but your home class is called `HomeScreen()`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user6327816  Home() is a different widget from HomeScreen().

Comment: Maybe you just didn't import search file into the file with MyApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.dart. You have to add the start page to initialRoute. You can remove the 'home' parameter.

```
    initialRoute: HomeScreen(),
    routes: {
              "/search" (context) => Search()
          },
```

So, home.dart file in;

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/search');
```